# Uploading files to Google Cloud Storage in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I've been trying to upload files to google cloud storage, but I couldn't.
Because createUploadUrl function is not returning any result.

My index.php is as follows.

```
<?php
require 'google/appengine/runtime/autoloader.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

echo "DDDDDD";
$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'test-server.appspot.com' ];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload.php', $options);

echo $upload_url;
?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Document upload</title>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var config = {
            support : "text/plain,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",      // Valid file formats
            form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
            dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
            uploadUrl: '<?php echo $upload_url; ?>'             // Server side upload url
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            initMultiUploader(config);
        });
    </script>

    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body lang="en">
<center>
    <h1 class="title">Document File Upload</h1>
</center>
<div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
    <h1>Drop Document File Here</h1>
</div>

<form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />
</form>
<div class="progressBar">
    <div class="status"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my upload.php is as follows.

```
<?php
   $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

   $gs_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   if (move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://test-server.appspot.com/'.$filename)) {
    echo "succeed!";
   } else echo "failed!";

?>
```

I think everything is fine, but the script is not working while executing createUploadUrl function.

Why is that?

Comment: Have you found answer for this? If yes please post.